# How to format Date in Adonisjs?

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

I need to send to database a date format like: DD-MM-YYYY.
Or some way  to format in frontend using Edge template

```
class AtendimentoSchema extends Schema {
  up () {
    this.create('atendimentos', (table) => {
      table.increments()
      table.date('data_emissao')
      table.timestamps()
    })
  }

  down () {
    this.drop('atendimentos')
  }
}
```

**I've tried**

```
class Atendimento extends Model {



        static formatDates (field, value) {
            if (field === 'data_emissao') {
              return value.format('DD-MM-YYYY')
            }
            return super.formatDates(field, value)
          }


}
```

** JSON output**

```
{
  "data_emissao": "2020-02-14",
  "id": 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

format accept default only create_at and update_at columns if you format another column then you use **get dates** like this

```
static get dates () {
    return super.dates.concat(['column_name'])
  }
```

in you case column name is `data_emissao`

Example :-

```
class Atendimento extends Model {


static get dates () {
    return super.dates.concat(['data_emissao'])
  }

static formatDates (field, value) {
     if (field === 'data_emissao') {
         return value.format('DD-MM-YYYY')
        }
     return super.formatDates(field, value)
   }


}
```

for more detail check [adonis.js official doc](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/lucid#_dates)

Comment: Thanks. Could I edit in this format?  'Its DD-MM-YYY  and HH:mm:ss'?  or only in frontend?

Comment: you will add any format this use a moment so you pass any format you want which supported by moment

Answer (score 2):

In 2021 (adonis-ts-app version 4)
use `@column.date()` decorator in your model:

```
@column.date()
public data_emissao: DateTime
```

see [the reference: ORM: Decorators](https://docs.adonisjs.com/reference/orm/decorators#columndate--columndatetime)

Then you can use luxons [toFormat()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting?id=toformat) to convert to a String:

```
data_emissao.toFormat('yyyy')
```

Comment: FYI. for anyone looking for it to work in the views, it will be available as well via that model attribute

Answer (score -1):

If you're able to use external packages try moment js, it will help you with that