# How to transform any column while fetching models

Tags: getter, accessor, adonis.js

I am using adonisjs 5 for my project to create REST APIs. I am fetching records from `Employees` table. But what I want want to do is to format dob column to `YYYY-MM-DD` when retrieving the data.

I am not sure how to achieve it ...

Thanks

I have tried many solution given on internet like
[How to format Date in Adonisjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60438472/how-to-format-date-in-adonisjs)